# Flash Builder 4.6 Mobile Orientation

Tags: android, flash-builder

I'm working with FlashBuilder 4.6 to develop Android app.
In the application there is a requirement of setting some values when device orientation changes. i.e. setting the values when the screen/device orientation changes from Landscape to Portrait and vice-verse.

Although Initially my application has **LandScape** orientation. And this requirement is on specific view.

I want every time when the screen/device orientation changes the values must be set there.
I am not getting the desired result.
Please guide me and tell me if I am at wrong in code or how can i achieve this.

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="{data}" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        viewActivate="view1_viewActivateHandler(event)"
        creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
   <![CDATA[
protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
{
    if(Accelerometer.isSupported)
    {
    accl = new Accelerometer();
        accl.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE,update);                //accl.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE,adjustImage);
    }
}
private function update(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
     this.stage.autoOrients = true;
     //in the below line I am attaching StageOrienationEvent that will adjust the 
     //values.
     stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE,adjust);
}
private function adjust(event:StageOrientationEvent):void
{
     if(event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT)
     {
    testVal.text ="After OR is LEFT";
     }
     else if(event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT)
     {
    testVal.text ="After OR is RIGHT"; 
     }
     else if(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE)
     {
    testVal.text ="StageAspectRatio is Landscape";
     }
     else if(StageAspectRatio.PORTRAIT)
     {
    testVal.text="StageAspectRatio is  Portrait";
     }
}

</fx:Script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution after spending two days on this.

in update function add **OrientationChanging Event** in stage.addEventListner.

```
private function update(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
  this.stage.autoOrients  = true;
  stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING,adjust);
}

private function adjust(event:StageOrientationEvent):void
{
  switch(event.afterOrientation)
  {
    case StageOrientation.DEFAULT:
       //Do Something here. The Portrait Position.
         break;
    case StageOrienatation.ROTATED_LEFT:
      //Do Something here when you rotate your phone portrait to left side.
       break;
    case StageOrienatation.ROTATED_RIGHT:
      //Do something here when you rotate your phone portrait to right side.
       break;
  }
}
```

Many thanks to all who viewed this question and try put their efforts for solution.   :)

Comment: Please Vote if you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

i am not a experimented coder! but : private function update(event:AccelerometerEvent):void should be : private function accl(event:AccelerometerEvent):void ?? or something like this in below code if(stage[not event].afterOrientation == ??? its just a opinion!

Comment: Thanks to join the thread. No there is no concern about the access specifier.